# Publishing ASP.net web project with Jenkins & MSDeploy

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, jenkins, msbuild

I have a Jenkins box running Server 2012r2. I have .Net 3.5, 4, 4.5 installed on it. Publishing .net Projects using 4 seems to work perfectly. Where things go wrong is with publishing a .net 4.5 web project.

I have three build steps:
1) Builds the SLN project
2) use msbuild to package the resulting compiling from step 1
3) use webdeploy to publish to a separate server.

The files make their way over to the new server but I then get the following error when navigating to the site:

```
  Method not found: '!!0[] System.Array.Empty()'.

    Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

    Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: '!!0[] System.Array.Empty()'.

    Source Error: 

    An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

    Stack Trace: 


    [MissingMethodException: Method not found: '!!0[] System.Array.Empty()'.]
       TestDeploySite.BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles) +0
       TestDeploySite.MvcApplication.Application_Start() +96

    [HttpException (0x80004005): Method not found: '!!0[] System.Array.Empty()'.]
       System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +9918157
       System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
       System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
       System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
       System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

    [HttpException (0x80004005): Method not found: '!!0[] System.Array.Empty()'.]
       System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9932052
       System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
       System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

I have narrowed the issue down to a file in the package/bin directory called 'TestDeploySite.dll'. When I publish this through VS 2015, it publishes fine. No errors appear in Jenkins with the build and no warnings exist. It feels like a .net version mismatch kind of issue.

MSBuild for 4.5 is configured with the following path:
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild

I have webdeploy installed and it seems to function fine. Once I get .net 4.5 projects deploying, I will have to refocus to publish .net Core 1 projects, so that should be... interesting.

Does anyone have some insight in to addressing this issue?

Comment: can you tell jenkins what version of msbuild to use?

Comment: Yeah. I am specifying MSbuild 14, but I really don't know 100% that it isn't building as 4.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up checking my msbuild.config for msbuild v14.0 and it showed supported frameworks being 4.0 AND 4.5.1... I went in to VS and changed my target to 4.5.1 and checked in changes to SVN. Executed job in Jenkins and the site is now publishing fine. A bit odd, though, that it can do 4.5.1 and not 4.5.0...

Either way, problem solved.